# Using QNetworkAccessManager across dll

Tags: qt, qt5, qtnetwork

I have a Qt5 application which uses `QNetworkAccessManager` for network requests which is accessible via a singleton and `QPluginLoader` to load extensions which add the functionality to the program. Currently I'm using static linking for plugins and *everything works just fine*.

However I want to switch to using dynamic libraries to separate the core functionality from other parts of the app. I've added the necessary `declspec`'s via macro, and made necessary adjustments in my .pro files.

The problem is that very often (like, 3 of 4 starts) `QNetworkAccessManager` when used from dlls just returns an empty request or a null pointer. No data, no error string, no headers.

This is the code I'm using for loading plugins:

```
template <typename PluginType>
static QList<PluginType*> loadModules() {
    QList<PluginType*> loadedModules;
    foreach (QObject* instance, QPluginLoader::staticInstances()) {
        PluginType* plugin = qobject_cast<PluginType*>(instance);
        if (plugin) {
            loadedModules << plugin;
        }
    }
    QDir modulesDir(qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/modules");
    foreach (QString fileName, modulesDir.entryList(QDir::Files)) {
        QPluginLoader loader(modulesDir.absoluteFilePath(fileName));
        QObject *instance = loader.instance();
        PluginType* plugin = qobject_cast<PluginType*>(instance);
        if (plugin) {
            loadedModules << plugin;
        }
    }
    return loadedModules;
}
```

Which is used in this non-static non-template overload called during the startup:

```
bool AppController::loadModules() {
m_window = new AppWindow();
/* some unimportant connection and splashscreen updating */
QList <ModuleInterface*> loadedModules = loadModules<ModuleInterface>();
foreach (ModuleInterface* module, loadedModules) {
    m_splash->showMessage(tr("Initializing module: %1").arg(module->getModuleName()),
                          Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignRight, Qt::white);
    module->preinit();
    QApplication::processEvents();
    // [1]
    ControllerInterface *controller = module->getMainController();
    m_window->addModule(module->getModuleName(),
                        QIcon(module->getIconPath()),
                        controller->primaryWidget(),
                        controller->settingsWidget());
    m_moduleControllers << controller;
}
m_window->addGeneralSettings((new GeneralSettingsController(m_window))->settingsWidget());
m_window->enableSettings();
/* restoring window geometry & showing it */
return true;
}
```

However, if I insert `QThread::sleep(1);` into the line marked **1**, it works okay, but the loading slows down and I highly doubt it is a stable solution that will work everywhere.
Also, the site I'm sending requests to is [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net).

Comment: Show us how you use QNetworkAccessManager. I suppose you just don't wait for its reponse.

Comment: @Bogdan In one part of the app, I'm using a wrapper that synchronizes it using a `QEventLoop`. (https://github.com/VeriTi/malstylerqt/blob/dll_heaven/base_app/networking/requestmanager.cpp) In the other I'm asynchronously parsing some XM from `QNetworkReply`. (https://github.com/VeriTi/malstylerqt/blob/dll_heaven/mod_covers/blink/blinkparser.cpp)

Comment: Your source seems OK to me. What do you mean that you get nullptr from QNetworkAccessManager? If you get QNetworkReplay==nullptr then IMHO it's a Qt bug, you could get replay with no data but definitely no nullptr (as fas as I understand the Qt doc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, now I have finally debugged it. Turned out I deleted internal QNetworkAccessManager in one of the classes that needed unsync access. That, and updating to Qt5.3 seem to have solved my problem.